# Zabbix SNMPv3 Agent Discovery

Tags: emulation, snmp, zabbix, snmpd, autodiscovery

I have a network emulation with Zabbix server, pc-1 with Zabbix-Agent and pc-2 with SNMPv3 Agent in VirtualBox.
[image: Topology]
With this discovery rule and action Zabbix easily discovers Agent on pc-1 and adds it to the hosts.
[image: Discovery Rule For Zabbix-Agent]
[image: Discovery Action For Zabbix-Agent]

I tried to make Zabbix to discover SNMPv3 Agent (pc-2). SNMP and all that needed is installed on both sides.
With this command from Zabbix server:

```
snmpget -u <username> -l authPriv -a MD5 -x DES -A <password> -X <password> 192.168.2.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

I get:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux pc2 4.4.0-92-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 10 09:04:33 UTC 2017 x86_64
```

But discovery rule and action don't work and Zabbix isn't adding 192.168.2.1 as host.

Here are discovery rule with action for SNMPv3 Agent:
[image: Discovery Rule for SNMPv3 Agent]
[image: Discovery Action For SNMPv3 Agent]

Maybe I missed something? There are no normal manuals for this. Thanks for help!

Comment: You have a pretty large network to discover there (/16) - are you sure it is not discovered, not that it takes a long time? Have you tried with a more targeted discovery rule that hits a much smaller range?

Comment: @Richlv Yes. You are right. I narrowed IP range down to specific IP of that VM 192.168.2.1 and it discovered it. Problem solved, thanks a lot! :) Should you give the answer below for me to close this?

Comment: Glad to hear that, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discovery range used is very large - the discovery is likely just slow and might work if a narrow, targeted range is specified.